# Passing selected item in listbox to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a Html.ListBox and upon selecting an Item I would like it to pass the item Id in so that I can call and load that selected Item's Information. Whats the best way to pass this id in to a script or maybe is there another way?

```
     @Html.ListBox("ListBoxName", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Epic>)ViewData["selectedestimate"], "Id", "Name"), new {@class = "ListBoxClass"})



        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".ListBoxClass").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from redirecting as it normally would
        $("#editid").load(this.href, function (response) {
            alert('hello'); //this just for testing
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to pass it to the function, you should just be able to do this:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").val();
```

Comment: How does it know what 'this' to refer to?

Comment: nvm that was a dumb question. Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Let me ask you this..how can I get the selected Items Name instead of the Id, or in other words how can I get the properties of whats in my ViewData in the script? Thx